# ViewPager setCurrentItem and dataSetChanged sequentially cause upcoming fragment won't display

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Recently, my team facing a problem, which happing when we tap a button to swith to another page in ViewPager, that page's fragment was a dummy fragment for some reason originally, so we shall replace it to the actual fragment.

first, when tap the button, we invoke `setCurrentItem()` to switch to the target page.

```
private void showTTGTab() {
    mFragmentVp.setCurrentItem(2, false);
}
```

setCurrentItem() would casuing ViewPager call the `onPageSelected()` back to inform page's movements, that was the place where we replacing the dummy fragment as the actual fragment.

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if (position == 2) onTTGSelect();
}

private void onTTGSelect() {
    if (mActualFramgnet == null) {
        mActualFramgnet = new my actual fragment();
        replaceToTTGFragment();
    }
}

private void replaceToTTGFragment() {
    mAdapter.removeFragment(my dummy fragment instance);

    mAdapter.addFragment(my actual fragment, 2);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**the ViewPager now displaying as blank, nothing to show.**

We localize the ViewPager's source code, print the positioning messages when onLayout, the last settled positions after `dataSetChanged()` were this:

```
Positioning #0 f=NewsFragment{42408810 #1} left=-1080 width=1080 currentScrollX=2160
Positioning #1 f=MeFragment{42408f70 #3} left=1080 width=1080 currentScrollX=2160
Positioning #2 f=TTGFragment{4242a610 #2} left=0 width=1080 currentScrollX=2160

Note : logs were modified and customized.
```

we see ViewPager's scrollX was 2160(width 1080 per fragment), none of our fragments enter its visible zone, which result in nothing show.

We trace and figure out it is the `scrollToItem()` scroll **x** to 2160 after setCurrentItem(), and the subsequent layouting made #2 fragment as primary item to populate x=0 position without scroll to the item that last setCurrentItem() wanted it to be scroll to.

does the dataset changed can realize the setCurrentItem just invoked, and scroll back to 0,0 after positioning settled?

I published my demo to helping understand the problem, please take a look at it :

https://github.com/vince-styling/viewpager-concurrent-datasetchange

Answer (score 0):

I find out a solution by take the `setPrimaryItem()` as the proper timing to scroll back, the key code below :

```
@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(..., int position, ...) {
    if (position == 2) {
        ViewPager.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
}
```

the whole solution lied in the github demo project.
still, I believe I could find the best place to scroll back If only the source code under my control.

If you have better solutions or I make some mistakes, please point out, thanks in advance.